# How to use the same code but with different variables

Tags: python, list, variables, numbers, valueerror

I want to make a code that allows me to check if the number I have entered is really a number and not a different character. Also, if it is a number, add its string to the list.

Something like this:

```
numbers = []
num1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
try:
    check = int(num1)
    numbers.append(num1)
    print("The number {} has been added.".format(num1))
except ValueError:
    print("Please, enter a number")
```

I have to do the same for several numbers, but the variables are different, like here:

```
num2 = input("Enter the next number: ")
try:
    check = int(num2)
    numbers.append(num2)
    print("The number {} has been added.".format(num2))
except ValueError:
    print("Please, enter a number")
```

Is there any way to create a code that does always the same process, but only changing the variable?

Comment: I think a **function** is what you're looking for.

Comment: Not only do you need a function but you also need to think about what will happen on ValueError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to continue adding numbers without copying your code block over and over, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

while len(numbers) < 5: #The five can be changed to any value for however many numbers you want in your list.
    num2 = input("Enter the next number: ")
    try:
        check = int(num2)
        numbers.append(num2)
        print("The number {} has been added.".format(num2))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please, enter a number")
```

Hopefully this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Create the list in a function (returning the list). Call the function with the number of integers required.

```
def get_ints(n):
  result = []
  while len(result) < n:
    try:
      v = int(input('Enter a number: '))
      result.append(v)
      print(f'Number {v} added')
    except ValueError:
      print('Integers only please')
  return result
```

Thus, if you want a list of 5 numbers then:

```
list_of_numbers = get_ints(5)
```